# Compare one row of a dataframe with rows of other dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, comparison-operators

I have two dataframes say `df and thresh_df`. The shape of `df` is say `1000*200` and `thresh_df` is `1*200`.

I need to compare the `thresh_df` row with each row of `df` element wise respectively and I have to fetch the corresponding column number whose values are less than the values of `thresh_df`.

I tried the following

```
compared_df = df.apply(lambda x : np.where(x < thresh_df.values))
```

But I get an empty dataframe! If question is unclear and need any explanations,please let me know in the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think apply is not necessary only compare one row DataFrame converted to `Series` by selecting first row:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({

         'B':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
         'C':[7,8,9,4,2,3],
         'D':[1,3,5,7,1,0],
         'E':[5,3,6,9,2,4],

})

thresh_df = pd.DataFrame({

         'B':[4],
         'C':[7],
         'D':[4],
         'E':[5],

})

compared_df  = df < thresh_df.iloc[0]
print (compared_df)
       B      C      D      E
0  False  False   True  False
1  False  False   True   True
2  False  False  False  False
3  False   True  False  False
4  False   True   True   True
5  False   True   True   True
```

Then use [`DataFrame.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) for filter at least one `True` per row and filter index values:

```
idx = df.index[compared_df.any(axis=1)]
print (idx)
Int64Index([0, 1, 3, 4, 5], dtype='int64')
```

**Detail**:

```
print (compared_df.any(axis=1))
0     True
1     True
2    False
3     True
4     True
5     True
dtype: bool
```

Comment: what if i want the indices where it is true

Comment: Hii...how is elements in thresh_df a list, they are elements. and I am getting the error
IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds

Comment: and no of columns in thresh_df and df must be same

Comment: Hii Jazrael, Can you please edit the code to get the columns where threshold is higher..!? instead of index . axis=0 didnt work for me!

Comment: @RamShankerG - It is really easy - `df = df[compared_df.any(axis=1)]`

Comment: Oh...damn sorry! got it! Thanks a bunch!